# Undefined reference for compiling and linking XML++ and GLIB

Tags: c++, xml, compiler-construction, build, linker

I would like to create a project in CodeBlocks IDE for C++ on Windows which will use the XML++ library. The library can be found here: http://libxmlplusplus.sourceforge.net/

It requires libxml2 and glibmm-2.4 libraries. I downloaded the source for each of these libraries and included all of the headers into my project by right clicking on "Build Options" ==> "Search Directories" tab ==> "Compiler" tab. I specified the header include files there. I modified the main.cpp file using the  source code from "examples/dom_parser" from the xml++/examples directory.

Now, I am having trouble with the following error message. I have never "linked" or used *.lib, *.dll files before... but I am now getting the following "undefined reference" error messages. Please let me know what I'd need to do in order to build this. Is there a particular file that I need to "link" and if so, where are these files located? I can't seem to find them in the source files that I extracted.

**Error Messages**

```
C:/Users/blah/Desktop/workspace/xmlpp/main.cpp:44: undefined reference to `xmlpp::ContentNode::is_white_space() const'
C:/Users/blah/Desktop/workspace/xmlpp/main.cpp:47: undefined reference to `xmlpp::Node::get_name() const'
C:/Users/blah/Desktop/workspace/xmlpp/main.cpp:49: undefined reference to `Glib::ustring::empty() const'
C:/Users/blah/Desktop/workspace/xmlpp/main.cpp:53: undefined reference to `xmlpp::Node::get_namespace_prefix() const'
C:/Users/blah/Desktop/workspace/xmlpp/main.cpp:54: undefined reference to `Glib::ustring::empty() const'
C:/Users/blah/Desktop/workspace/xmlpp/main.cpp:55: undefined reference to `Glib::operator<<(std::ostream&, Glib::ustring const&)'
C:/Users/blah/Desktop/workspace/xmlpp/main.cpp:57: undefined reference to `Glib::operator<<(std::ostream&, Glib::ustring const&)'
C:/Users/blah/Desktop/workspace/xmlpp/main.cpp:57: undefined reference to `Glib::operator<<(std::ostream&, Glib::ustring const&)'
C:/Users/blah/Desktop/workspace/xmlpp/main.cpp:57: undefined reference to `Glib::ustring::~ustring()'
C:/Users/blah/Desktop/workspace/xmlpp/main.cpp:69: undefined reference to `xmlpp::ContentNode::get_content() const'
C:/Users/blah/Desktop/workspace/xmlpp/main.cpp:69: undefined reference to `Glib::operator<<(std::ostream&, Glib::ustring const&)'
C:/Users/blah/Desktop/workspace/xmlpp/main.cpp:69: undefined reference to `Glib::ustring::~ustring()'
C:/Users/blah/Desktop/workspace/xmlpp/main.cpp:74: undefined reference to `xmlpp::ContentNode::get_content() const'
C:/Users/blah/Desktop/workspace/xmlpp/main.cpp:74: undefined reference to `Glib::operator<<(std::ostream&, Glib::ustring const&)'
C:/Users/blah/Desktop/workspace/xmlpp/main.cpp:74: undefined reference to `Glib::ustring::~ustring()'
C:/Users/blah/Desktop/workspace/xmlpp/main.cpp:79: undefined reference to `xmlpp::ContentNode::get_content() const'
C:/Users/blah/Desktop/workspace/xmlpp/main.cpp:79: undefined reference to `Glib::operator<<(std::ostream&, Glib::ustring const&)'
C:/Users/blah/Desktop/workspace/xmlpp/main.cpp:79: undefined reference to `Glib::ustring::~ustring()'
C:/Users/blah/Desktop/workspace/xmlpp/main.cpp:87: undefined reference to `xmlpp::Node::get_line() const'
C:/Users/blah/Desktop/workspace/xmlpp/main.cpp:90: undefined reference to `xmlpp::Element::get_attributes() const'
C:/Users/blah/Desktop/workspace/xmlpp/main.cpp:96: undefined reference to `xmlpp::Node::get_namespace_prefix() const'
C:/Users/blah/Desktop/workspace/xmlpp/main.cpp:97: undefined reference to `Glib::ustring::empty() const'
C:/Users/blah/Desktop/workspace/xmlpp/main.cpp:98: undefined reference to `xmlpp::Attribute::get_value() const'
C:/Users/blah/Desktop/workspace/xmlpp/main.cpp:98: undefined reference to `xmlpp::Attribute::get_name() const'
C:/Users/blah/Desktop/workspace/xmlpp/main.cpp:98: undefined reference to `Glib::operator<<(std::ostream&, Glib::ustring const&)'
C:/Users/blah/Desktop/workspace/xmlpp/main.cpp:98: undefined reference to `Glib::operator<<(std::ostream&, Glib::ustring const&)'
C:/Users/blah/Desktop/workspace/xmlpp/main.cpp:98: undefined reference to `Glib::ustring::~ustring()'
C:/Users/blah/Desktop/workspace/xmlpp/main.cpp:98: undefined reference to `Glib::ustring::~ustring()'
C:/Users/blah/Desktop/workspace/xmlpp/main.cpp:100: undefined reference to `xmlpp::Attribute::get_value() const'
C:/Users/blah/Desktop/workspace/xmlpp/main.cpp:100: undefined reference to `xmlpp::Attribute::get_name() const'
C:/Users/blah/Desktop/workspace/xmlpp/main.cpp:100: undefined reference to `Glib::operator<<(std::ostream&, Glib::ustring const&)'
C:/Users/blah/Desktop/workspace/xmlpp/main.cpp:100: undefined reference to `Glib::operator<<(std::ostream&, Glib::ustring const&)'
C:/Users/blah/Desktop/workspace/xmlpp/main.cpp:100: undefined reference to `Glib::operator<<(std::ostream&, Glib::ustring const&)'
C:/Users/blah/Desktop/workspace/xmlpp/main.cpp:100: undefined reference to `Glib::ustring::~ustring()'
C:/Users/blah/Desktop/workspace/xmlpp/main.cpp:100: undefined reference to `Glib::ustring::~ustring()'
C:/Users/blah/Desktop/workspace/xmlpp/main.cpp:101: undefined reference to `Glib::ustring::~ustring()'
C:/Users/blah/Desktop/workspace/xmlpp/main.cpp:103: undefined reference to `Glib::ustring::ustring()'
C:/Users/blah/Desktop/workspace/xmlpp/main.cpp:103: undefined reference to `Glib::ustring::ustring(char const*)'
C:/Users/blah/Desktop/workspace/xmlpp/main.cpp:103: undefined reference to `xmlpp::Element::get_attribute(Glib::ustring const&, Glib::ustring const&) const'
C:/Users/blah/Desktop/workspace/xmlpp/main.cpp:103: undefined reference to `Glib::ustring::~ustring()'
C:/Users/blah/Desktop/workspace/xmlpp/main.cpp:103: undefined reference to `Glib::ustring::~ustring()'
C:/Users/blah/Desktop/workspace/xmlpp/main.cpp:106: undefined reference to `xmlpp::Attribute::get_value() const'
C:/Users/blah/Desktop/workspace/xmlpp/main.cpp:106: undefined reference to `Glib::operator<<(std::ostream&, Glib::ustring const&)'
C:/Users/blah/Desktop/workspace/xmlpp/main.cpp:106: undefined reference to `Glib::ustring::~ustring()'
C:/Users/blah/Desktop/workspace/xmlpp/main.cpp:113: undefined reference to `Glib::ustring::ustring()'
C:/Users/blah/Desktop/workspace/xmlpp/main.cpp:113: undefined reference to `xmlpp::Node::get_children(Glib::ustring const&) const'
C:/Users/blah/Desktop/workspace/xmlpp/main.cpp:113: undefined reference to `Glib::ustring::~ustring()'
C:/Users/blah/Desktop/workspace/xmlpp/main.cpp:118: undefined reference to `Glib::ustring::~ustring()'
C:/Users/blah/Desktop/workspace/xmlpp/main.cpp:57: undefined reference to `Glib::ustring::~ustring()'
C:/Users/blah/Desktop/workspace/xmlpp/main.cpp:69: undefined reference to `Glib::ustring::~ustring()'
```

The libxml++ website (http://libxmlplusplus.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/html/) contains the following information:

```
**Compilation and Linking**

To use libxml++ in your application, you must tell the compiler where to find the include headers and where to find the libxml++ library. libxml++ provides a pkg-config .pc file to make this easy. For instance, the following command will provide the necessary compiler options: pkg-config libxml++-2.6 --cflags --libs

When using autoconf and automake, this is even easier with the PKG_CHECK_MODULES macro in your configure.ac file. For instance:

    PKG_CHECK_MODULES(SOMEAPP, libxml++-2.6 >= 2.10.0)
    AC_SUBST(SOMEAPP_CFLAGS)
    AC_SUBST(SOMEAPP_LIBS)
```

However, how would this be done in Windows in the CodeBlocks IDE when building this c++ project? I can't seem to figure out what it means by pkg-config and how to use --cflags and --libs.